# How to run a custom Java annotation processor locally with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I have a custom annotation processor and would like to test it locally, but I'm having trouble configuring the annotation processor for this.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "com.abb.Cleaner"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    implementation("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc7")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc7")

}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**annotation processor**

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.abb.Cleaner")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class CleanerProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        //...
        return true;
    }
}
```

**run ./gradlew clean build**

[image]

How can I run it locally through a `main` method to see if the annotation is working?

Ex:

```
public class Test {

    @Cleanner
    private String text1;
    @Cleanner
    private String text2;

    public Test(String text1, String text2) {
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    // get / set

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Testetest = new Test("car", "ferrai");
        System.out.println(teste.getText1);
        System.out.println(test.getText2());
    }
}
```